# how to scroll two listview builder (one -two listview builder is in top-bottom)simultaneously by using listen their index

Tags: flutter, dart

[![enter image description here][1]][1]The one listview builder is in top,another is in bottom.I wants the both listvew builder should scroll simultaneously by analyze their index.Even i scroll it ,the first listview will be get index[2],at the same time the second one is always get index[2],here the listview builder have different sizedbox

this is my code

```
  child: PageView.builder(
                      
                        **itemBuilder: (context, key) => WeatherCityitem(
                              verseTamil: verseTamil,
                              verseEnglish: verseEnglish,
                            ),**
```

it is an another class that would be called by another item inside the pageview builder

```
>     
>     class WeatherCityitem extends StatefulWidget {
>       WeatherCityitem(
>           {Key? key, required this.verseTamil, required this.verseEnglish});
>       @override
>       State createState() => _WeatherCityitemState();
>     }
>     
>     enum ScrollingList {
>       none,
>       top,
>       bottom,
>     }
>     
>     class _WeatherCityitemState extends State<WeatherCityitem> {

>       ScrollController listTamilVerse = ScrollController();
>       ScrollController listEnglishVerse = ScrollController();
>       var _appcolor = Default.backgroundColor;
>       var _fontcolor = Default.fontcolor;
>       double fontSized = Get.find<StateController>().fontSize;
>       @override
>       void initState() {
>         super.initState();
>         _controllerTop = ScrollController();
>         _controllerBottom = ScrollController();
>       }

>     
>       @override
>       Widget build(BuildContext context) {
>         return Scaffold(
>           body: ListView(
>             shrinkWrap: true,
>             children: [
>               SizedBox(
>                 height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height *
>                     ComponentSize.container6height,
>                 child: NotificationListener<ScrollNotification>(
>                   onNotification: (notification) {
>                     if (notification is ScrollStartNotification) {
>                       if (scrollingList == ScrollingList.none) {
>                         scrollingList = ScrollingList.top;
>                       }
>                     } else if (notification is ScrollEndNotification) {
>                       if (scrollingList == ScrollingList.top) {
>                         scrollingList = ScrollingList.none;
>                       }
>                     }
>                     if (scrollingList == ScrollingList.top) {
>                       _controllerBottom.jumpTo(_controllerTop.offset);
>                     }
>                     return true;
>                   },
>                   child: ListView.builder(
>                     controller: _controllerTop,
>                     shrinkWrap: true,
>                     physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),
>                     itemCount: widget.verseTamil.length,
>                     itemBuilder: (context, index) { ..........
>               },
>                   ),
>                 ),
>               ),
>               SizedBox(
>                 height: 1,
>                 child: Divider(
>                   thickness: 1.8,
>                   color: AppColor.container,
>                 ),
>               ),
>               SizedBox(
>                 height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height *
>                     ComponentSize.container6height,
>                 child: NotificationListener<ScrollNotification>(
>                   onNotification: (notification) {
>                     if (notification is ScrollStartNotification) {
>                       if (scrollingList == ScrollingList.none) {
>                         scrollingList = ScrollingList.bottom;
>                       }
>                     } else if (notification is ScrollEndNotification) {
>                       if (scrollingList == ScrollingList.bottom) {
>                         scrollingList = ScrollingList.none;
>                       }
>                     }
>                     if (scrollingList == ScrollingList.bottom) {

                      _controllerTop.jumpTo(_controllerBottom.offset);

>                     }
>                     return true;
>                   },
>                  child: ListView.builder(
>                     controller: _controllerBottom,
>                     itemCount: widget.verseEnglish.length,
>                     shrinkWrap: true,
>                     physics: const ClampingScrollPhysics(),
>                     itemBuilder: (context, index) {
>                    ..........
>                     },
>                   ),
>                 ),
>               ),
>             ],
>           ),
>         );
>       }
>     }
```

I want that the  two listview builder would be scrolled by according their index value[![this is the picture][the two listview builder are simultaneously scroll ]][according thier index,the listview builder will be scrollable]

Comment: Can you include your code-snippet what you've tried so far

Answer (score 0):

It's quite complex to do in flutter. You might not able to do it with index but you can achieve similar behavior while sync scrolling of two lists. If one list scrolls the other will also scroll. To achieve this behavior you can add [`linked_scroll_controller`](https://pub.dev/packages/linked_scroll_controller) to your `pubspec.yaml`

```dart
class LinkedScrollables extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _LinkedScrollablesState createState() => _LinkedScrollablesState();
}

class _LinkedScrollablesState extends State<LinkedScrollables> {
  LinkedScrollControllerGroup _controllers;
  ScrollController _letters;
  ScrollController _numbers;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controllers = LinkedScrollControllerGroup();
    _letters = _controllers.addAndGet();
    _numbers = _controllers.addAndGet();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _letters.dispose();
    _numbers.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Directionality(
      textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
      child: Row(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: ListView(
              controller: _letters,
              children: <Widget>[
                _Tile('Hello A'),
                _Tile('Hello B'),
                _Tile('Hello C'),
                _Tile('Hello D'),
                _Tile('Hello E'),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: ListView(
              controller: _numbers,
              children: <Widget>[
                _Tile('Hello 1'),
                _Tile('Hello 2'),
                _Tile('Hello 3'),
                _Tile('Hello 4'),
                _Tile('Hello 5'),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class _Tile extends StatelessWidget {
  final String caption;

  _Tile(this.caption);

  @override
  Widget build(_) => Container(
        margin: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        height: 250.0,
        child: Center(child: Text(caption)),
      );
}
```

Comment: It has different text length ,so the index value could be varient ,i could not get the scroll simultaneously according their index

Comment: If the length is different then how are you going to achieve similar behaviour with index.

Comment: I don't know bro,you have any idea for that

Comment: Seems like its not possible.